# how to push string into new array?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and is going through the tutorials here on www.codeacademy.com. I am trying to push a string into a new array however i am getting an error when i run the code
saying

***"Oops, try again! It looks like your second 'for' loop isn't pushing values to the hits array. Make sure it's working properly and that myWord text appears somewhere in the text variable."***

I have looked over the code but have no clue as to where the fault is?

```
var someText = "This is some text and i am trying to push this text into a new string containing the string text.";

var myWord = "text";

var hits = [];

for (var i = 0; i < someText.length; i++) {
    if (someText[i] === myWord[0]) {
        for (var j = i; j < someText[i] + myWord.length; j++) {
            hits = [];
            hits.push("text");
            hits[0]; //equals 'text'

        }
    }
}
```

any ideas how to get this to work?

Comment: Whats going on right here: `someText[i]+myWord.length;`

Comment: someText[i]+myWord.length is the stopping condition for the second loop. perhaps i didn't need to reference the index :S

Comment: Well, whats are you trying to check in that condition?

Comment: I am trying to check 'someText' for the first letter in 'myWord' then push (add) the number of characters equal to 'myWord's' length to an array.

Comment: Just saying, this condition `j < someText[i] + myWord.length` is going to evaluate to something like `j < t20`

Comment: i suspect my for loop is incorrect?

Comment: Yeah, I'm just not really sure what that second loop is for

Comment: The loop is supposed to make sure each character of 'myWord' gets pushed to the final array. So i want to add each character into the array until it hits the length of 'myWord'. For example, if 'myWord' was 15 letters long, the loop should add 15 characters to hits if it ever sees the first letter of 'myWord' in 'someText'

Comment: Then run `j < myWord.length`, ditch that `someText` :)

Comment: hallelujah! i ditched the someText and just left it like this >> j < i + myWord.length and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Posted a quick answer for future reference, glad it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second loop iteration is doing an illegal comparison `j < someText[i] + myWord.length;`. Remove that `someText[i]` from the mix and it'll work: `j < myWord.length`

Answer (score 2):

You reset `hits` at each iteration.

Remove `hits = []` in your loop.